# Xcode build error: PhaseScriptExecution Strip\ Frameworks /appName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROD.build/Script-8CBD27422B744FC9C0407AA3.sh

Tags: react-native, xcode10.1

I am really struggling to understand the internals of Xcode, the latest error I am getting is this one:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Strip\ Frameworks /Users/danale/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/NFIBEngage.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROD.build/Script-8CBD27422B744FC9C0407AA3.sh

(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NFIBEngage.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

How do I go about resolving this? None of what I have seen thus far has worked. The application itself loads just fine inside of simulator, but I keep getting build failures.

I was getting this error when I had React Native 0.53.3 and React 16.2 and I continue to get this error when I upgraded to React Native 0.59.9 and React 16.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PhaseScriptExecution Strip\ Frameworks /appName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROD.build/Script-8CBD27422B744FC9C0407AA3.sh` Xcode build error was related to some configuration inside of `ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` where the configuration in those files look something like this:

```
9B41C3B09EAC07B2B007DE0F /* Strip Frameworks */ = {
            isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
            );
            inputPaths = (
            );
            name = "Strip Frameworks";
            outputPaths = (
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
            shellPath = /bin/sh;
            shellScript = "bash \"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/InstabugCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh\"\n";
        };
```

Once I completely removed references to `8CBD27422B744FC9C0407AA3` the error went away.